# Sub-domain with www does not resolve

Tags: dns

I have a Heroku App hosted at eye-cs.herokuapp.com and we've also added a CNAME record to the DNS records that points eye.circularsociety.com to it and it works perfectly.

I added another DNS CNAME record for www.eye.circularsociety.com to eye-cs.herokuapp.com and I always get the ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the record for www.eye.circularsociety.com to the DNS server that's authoritative for circularsociety.com, not herokuapp.com